# Spring remove printout Could not load properties from URL

Tags: java, spring, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm building a gradle plugin in which I want to give users the ability to override some properties from an external file.
I'm using the Spring propertyPlaceholderConfigurer in order to set a few destinations where users can place their files, This works as expected.
My problem is that when running my plugin Spring prints out to the console: "Could not load properties from URL [...]"
Does anyone have any idea how I would go about squelching this message?

I've tried overriding logback and sl4j to no avail.

My Spring application-context xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd"
   default-lazy-init="true">

<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Repository and @Service -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test"/>

<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/conf/plugin.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/conf/plugin.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/conf/plugin-override.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement custom logic to set locations you can extend `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` like

```
class CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    public void setFileName(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = findPropertyFile(fileName);  // implement property file loading
        super.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(file));
    }
```

and use it like

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="package.CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ">
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: There's a good chance this would work but for my case it's a bit overkill

Comment: So I ended up using your solution although the function I needed to override was setLocations

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there are no such files.

Try to add configs below to the `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

```
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
```

Comment: You're right that the files don't exist, and the ignore properties do work by not failing the build but, sadly, the debug message is still printed out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the message was originating in PropertiesLoaderSupport
at the loadProperties method:

```
if (this.ignoreResourceNotFound) {
                    if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                        logger.warn("Could not load properties from " + location + ": " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

So what I ended up doing is set the logger level in my gradle task to Error as follows:

```
task.doFirst {
    logger.context.level = LogLevel.ERROR
    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.ERROR
}
```