# How to handle CORS URLs on Prod/Dev environments?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, cors

In our Spring Boot app, we made the first deployment on our Quality environment and now we want to make it simple defining URLs to accept petitions from our FrontEnd application.

We build our application with maven and then we execute it with the command

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

We thought we could set the URL on the `application.properties/application-prod.properties` file, but this does not work as in execution time it is null. Another workaround would be somehow to get the parameter `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` we pass when running the application and then take one URL or another but this seems to be a little dirty...

So what do you guys would do? I was impressed not finding anything on google, apparently people have different workarounds or I am searching in the wrong way.

**Edit**
Cross Origin info:
This is how we implemented it at first.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = BasicConfiguration.CLIENT_URL)
```

And this is how we want to do it now with a filter with Spring Security

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter, ApplicationContextAware {
    @Value("${urlServer}")
    private String urlServer;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", urlServer);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Of course urlServer is defined in application.properties with its corresponding metadata.

**EDIT 2**
How I initialize the filter:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new CorsFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/sessionLogin");
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code where CORS urls being set? Actually it should works perfectly fine with application.properties and this is right way to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797127/spring-remove-printout-could-not-load-properties-from-url/44797337#comment76575201_44797337 so you can define properties from external files overriding ones from application.properties

Comment: How do you create your CorsFilter object? I guess you just create it like `new CorsFilter()` so it's not a spring bean and it's not managed by spring context. That's why your property cannot be injected

Comment: I added the initialization @Leffchik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you `CorsFilter` is not a spring bean. You can eather define it like a bean, or do something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter(@Value("${app.cors.url.server}") String urlServer) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter();
        corsFilter.setUrlServer(urlServer);
        registration.setFilter(corsFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/sessionLogin");
        return registration;
    }
```

Of course, you will need to define setter in your `CorsFilter` for `urlServer` field

Comment: Thanks! I finnally solved making another method to just return a new Corsfilter() with a @Bean annotation.
It worked! Indeed the problem was that the initialization of the CorsFilter was not withing Spring Context.